Allow admin to impersonate a tenant in a multi-tenant application which uses ASP.NET Identity
I have a multi-tenant application which has Tenant users (identified by the roles TenantSupport and TenantTechnical) and Admin users (identified by the roles AdminSupport and AdminTechnical)
All users ClaimsPrincipals contain a Claim which stores their TenantId in order to restrict access and carry out data isolation.
Admin users can setup new tenants etc. whilst Tenant users just operate the tenant application.
Tenant users often require support. The ability for an Admin user to temporarily become a Tenant user.
My idea was to allow an Admin user to impersonate a selected Tenant by signing them out and immediately signing them back in again using the target TenantId and TenantSupport role on the new ClaimsPrincipal.
Im struggling to achieve that though, because the SignInManager determines the user's roles from the database, so the roles always end up including the AdminSupport / AdminTechnical roles
Anyone with experience on impersonating users in ASP.NET Identity?

SOLVED
Interestingly, when I originally searched for a solution to this I used the term 'Emulate' rather than 'Impersonate' which yielded no results of any use. However, my recent searches using 'Impersonate' lead me to the solution below.
// make a copy of the current user principal to use as a basis for the impersonated one
var claimsPrincipal = User.Clone();

var identity = claimsPrincipal.Identities.First();

// make a list of admin claims to remove which will be replaced by tenant claims
var oldRoleClaims = identity.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Role || c.Type == ApplicationSignInManager.TENTANTID).ToList();

// remove old admin claims
foreach (var roleClaim in oldRoleClaims)
    identity.RemoveClaim(roleClaim);

// add new tenant user claims
identity.AddClaims(new List<Claim>
{
    new Claim("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid", impersonateTenantId),
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "TenantSupport"),
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "TenantTechnical")
});

// sign out the current user
await HttpContext.SignOutAsync();

// sign in with the new claims principal
await HttpContext.SignInAsync(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme, claimsPrincipal);

